# Нужно закодировать урл также как это делает браузер (php)

Tags: php

например, если вбить в браузере

> [https://yandex.ru/search/?text=привет](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)

то браузер сделает запрос к серверу

> https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82

Нужно сделать такую же функцию.

Использовать напрямую **Urlencode** не подходит, потому что нужно кодировать выборочно, т.е. только русские буквы и прочие *utf* символы, а всякие **% & /** оставлять как есть.

Понятно, что можно написать самому, но может, какая-то библиотека есть для этого?

Comment: Вбейте в тот же яндекс % и & и поимёте, что оставлять их как есть не стоит :)

Comment: В браузер, а не в яндекс. Яндекс тут вообще не при чем

Comment: а уж если вобьёте в адресную строку кирилический домен, то вообще ошалеете.

Comment: А вы вбейте именно в яндекс и посмотрите что получится :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Простого решения нет. В качестве отправной точки можно парсить вручную составные части. В вашем примере прокатит такой вариант, но ловите ошибки, когда части не объявлены. Например, мне сейчас было в лом проверять наличие пути и параметров запроса.

```
/** черновой набросок решения */
function unsafe_url_encode($url) { 
    $url_parts =parse_url ($url); /**  разбить url на части */

    $path = preg_split('#/#', $url_parts['path']); /** разбить путь на части */  
    $path = array_map('urlencode',$path); /* кодировать каждую часть пути */
    $url_parts['path'] = implode('/',$path);

    $args = preg_split('#&#', $url_parts['query']); /** разбить параметры на части, и обработать их */
    foreach ($args as $k=>$v) {
        $argument = preg_split('#=#',$v);
        $argument = array_map('urlencode', $argument);
        $args[$k] = implode('=',$argument);
    }

    /** собрать всё в кучу */
    $args = implode('&',$args);
    $url_parts['query'] = $args;
    extract ($url_parts);

    $retval = "${scheme}://${host}${path}";
    if ( strlen($query)) $retval .= "?${query}"; 
    if ( isset ($fragment)) $retval .= '#'.urlencode($fragment);
    return $retval;
}

echo unsafe_url_encode ("https://yandex.ru/search/?text=привет");
```

Онлайн-сэндбокс с примером: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd073f99c4a76f08ec34aef44e810ce4aafdaf47